# Why is python list storing each character in BeautifulSoup tags?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

def getLinks(pathUrl):
    a=[]
    html = urlopen(xiny+pathUrl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    nameList = soup.findAll("td",{"class":"name"})
    for name in nameList:
        aLink = name.find("a").attrs["href"]
        print(aLink)
        a += aLink
    return a
xiny = 'https://learnxinyminutes.com'
links = getLinks("/")
print(links)
```

I'm trying to get the relative pathname links using bs4 and store them in a list, but when I do this, it concatenates each individual character of the pathnames instead of the just the pathname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+=` is the same as `list.extend` which takes an *iterable* and extends the list with the contents of the iterable, what you want is to *append:*

```
In [45]: l = []

In [46]: s = "foobar"

In [47]: l.append(s) 

In [48]: l
Out[48]: ['foobar']

In [49]: l += s

In [50]: l
Out[50]: ['foobar', 'f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']

In [51]: l.extend(s)
In [52]: l
Out[52]: ['foobar', 'f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']
```

Using *+=* or *.extend* is logically equivalent to doing:

```
In [53]: l = []

In [54]: for ele in s:
   ....:     l.append(ele)
   ....:     
In [55]: l
Out[55]: ['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']
```

So that is why you see each char as an individual element in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use `a.append(aLink)` to add items to your list. Tested, works for me. I would avoid using `+=` for concatenating a list, it's a bit hackey :)

Comment: `+=` won't work because `aLink` is a string and `a` is a list if you add an interable (like a string) to a list with `+=`, each element of the iterable is added. try `>>> a = []; a+="foo";a` in a python shell.